# Fill table with datas in .ts

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a simple question but can not find the answer anywhere

I have this class :

```js
export class expCarac {
  constructor(
    algorithm : String,
    name: String,
    aggType : String,
    score: number,
  ){
    Object.assign(this, {algorithm:algorithm, name: name, aggType:aggType, score:score});
  }
}
```

and this in my typescript :

```js
experiment1 = [
    new expCarac ("algo", "fake_scalar_1", "mean", 0.35945656),
    new expCarac ("algo", "step_length_right", "mean", 0.95962433),
    new expCarac ("algo", "step_length_right", "std", 0.01945656),
    new expCarac ("algo", "step_length_left", "mean", 0.9536)
  ];
  expermient2 = [
    new expCarac ("algo", "fake_scalar_1", "mean", 0.55210394),
    new expCarac ("algo", "step_length_right", "mean", 0.43753877),
    new expCarac ("algo", "step_length_right", "std", 0.98195),
    new expCarac ("algo", "step_length_left", "mean", 0.9716824)
  ];
```

And I simply want to display it in a table with html but can't find my way to separate datas because the td will only fill 1 box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let expcarac of experiment2" >
          <td>{{expcarac.algorithm}}</td>
          <td>{{expcarac.name}}</td>
          <td>{{expcarac.aggType}}</td>
          <td>{{expcarac.score}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Sorry, it was really simple